# EntityDbContext SaveChanges : What are the differences between these two codes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

In order to performance, exception capturing and etc., What are the differences between these two codes:

```
           int count = 0;
           foreach (var record in SomeDbEntityList)
            {
                count++;
                dbContext.SomeDbEntity.Add(record);
                if (count > 500)
                {
                  dbContext.SaveChanges();
                  count = 0;
                }
            }
            //LeftOver
            if (count > 0)
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The direct code:

```
            foreach (var record in SomeDbEntityList)
            {
                dbContext.SomeDbEntity.Add(record);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The first code saves the new changes on the DB after 500 (or less)
   records are entity, so 500 updates/inserts are made to the DB on the
   same time.

   - **Advantages**: you don't go for every record in the DB.
   - **Disadvantages**: if any of these records have an error (issue), than **none** of the records will be updated.
2. The second code saves directly to the DB.

Please take a look at [Unit of Work](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern) design pattern.